# How to insert random data into a SQLite table using only queries?

Tags: sqlite

I have a test SQLite table:

```
CREATE TABLE test (
  id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL, 
  x REAL NOT NULL  DEFAULT (RANDOM()),
  y REAL NOT NULL  DEFAULT (RANDOM()),
  z REAL NOT NULL  DEFAULT (RANDOM())
)
```

and I want to create over thousands of rows of random data, and how can I do it using a SQL query? I can't use a SQL `FOR` loop because loops are not supported in SQLite, and I'm thinking of `SELECT`ing all the data from the table then `INSERT` for each row, so the number of rows double each time I execute the query. I think that requires a nested query, which I don't understand.

Comment: you don't do it in sql. you do it in a client app (e.g. php, perl, python, etc...).

Comment: I'm interested in the hacky solutions right now.

Comment: that is the hacky solution.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Going for hacky, this'll insert up to 2048 random rows in one go, decide how many by setting the limit;

```
INSERT INTO TEST (x,y,z)
  SELECT RANDOM(), RANDOM(), RANDOM()
   FROM (SELECT * FROM (
         (SELECT 0 UNION ALL SELECT 1) t2, 
         (SELECT 0 UNION ALL SELECT 1) t4,
         (SELECT 0 UNION ALL SELECT 1) t8,
         (SELECT 0 UNION ALL SELECT 1) t16,
         (SELECT 0 UNION ALL SELECT 1) t32,
         (SELECT 0 UNION ALL SELECT 1) t64,
         (SELECT 0 UNION ALL SELECT 1) t128,
         (SELECT 0 UNION ALL SELECT 1) t256,
         (SELECT 0 UNION ALL SELECT 1) t512,
         (SELECT 0 UNION ALL SELECT 1) t1024,
         (SELECT 0 UNION ALL SELECT 1) t2048
         )
    ) LIMIT 246;
```

Answer (score 9):

You can use a [recursive query](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_with.html#recursivecte).

This query generates a table with 1000 random numbers:

```
CREATE TABLE test(field1);

INSERT INTO test
  WITH RECURSIVE
    cte(x) AS (
       SELECT random()
       UNION ALL
       SELECT random()
         FROM cte
        LIMIT 1000
  )
SELECT x FROM cte;
```

Answer (score 3):

I agree with Stenci, you can use a [recursive query](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_with.html#recursivecte). Since [SQLite Release 3.8.3 On 2014-02-03](http://www.sqlite.org/releaselog/3_8_3.html) has added support for CTEs.
The following query generates the table the OP has requested with 1000 random numbers:

```
CREATE TABLE test (
  id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL, 
  x REAL NOT NULL,
  y REAL NOT NULL,
  z REAL NOT NULL
);
INSERT INTO test
    WITH RECURSIVE
      cnt( id, x, y, z) AS (
      VALUES(1 , random(), random(), random()) UNION ALL 
      SELECT id+1,random(),random(), random() FROM cnt WHERE ID<1000)
    select * from cnt;
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are in the sqlite3 shell, you can use [generate_series()](https://sqlite.org/series.html):

`insert into test (x,y,z) select random(), random(), random() from generate_series(1, 10000);`

Answer (score 1):

This seems to do what you want. You would have to run it a few times since it doubles the number of existing rows each time. And you need to have at least one row of data present to begin with.

`insert into test select random(), random(), random(), random() from test;`

Comment: I would suggest: `insert into test select * from test`

Answer (score 0):

Just mix the functions RANDOM() and ABS() with the operation % (mod).

Example: insert random number from 0 to 10

```
INSERT INTO test(field1) VALUES( abs(random() % 11) );
```